# select_related() in generic class-based views

Tags: django, django-class-based-views

I'm just getting started with the new(ish) class-based views, and I am wondering what's the best way to get select_related() in there. Here's my view:

```
class PostDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Post
```

The post comes from the 'slug' in the URL. This works fine, but, I would like to get select_related() in there to reduce the number of queries.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Specify a `queryset` instead of `model`:

```
class PostDetailView(DetailView):
    queryset = Post.objects.select_related()
```

(See [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/mixins-single-object/#django.views.generic.detail.SingleObjectMixin.model)).